# how to print $GLOBALS displaying in string?

Tags: php

how to print $GLOBALS displaying in string?
the is a very simpple demo bellow , sometimes I need to print $GLOBALS of a complex page , and there many html codes in vars, they display as html which I only want them to be string, how to do that?

```
<pre>
<?php

$html='<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

[image]

Comment: user `echo "<pre>"; print_r... echo "</pre>";`

Comment: @CooPer OP already doing `<pre>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo htmlentities(print_r($GLOBALS, true));`

Answer (score 1):

If your `$GLOBALS` contains html link then you need to remove `HTML` tags as below,

```
echo "<pre>".strip_tags(print_r($GLOBALS))."</pre>";
```

**OR**

```
echo "<pre>".print_r(strip_tags($GLOBALS))."</pre>";
```